# Run all VirusTotal scanners on file released from MSBuild through SQL

Tags: invantive-sql

We build software deliverables as files on a build server. Once every few months, some of these files are rejected by some of the virus scanners available.

I want to avoid post-shipment issues with the files.

How can I use the VirusTotal provider with Invantive SQL in my build process to early detect false positives on our new software?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to first upload all files eligible for virus infection using:

```
insert into VirusScanRequests(type, name, contents, orig_system_reference) 
select 'file'
,      fle.file_path
,      rfe.file_contents
,      fle.file_path orig_system_reference
from   ( select 'exe' ext from dual@datadictionary
         union all
         select 'dat' from dual@datadictionary
         union all
         select 'dll' from dual@datadictionary
         union all
         select 'pdf' from dual@datadictionary
         union all
         select 'chm' from dual@datadictionary
       ) ext
join   files('c:\PATH', '*.' || ext.ext, false)@os 
       fle
join   read_file(fle.file_path)@os rfe
on     length(rfe.file_contents) < 32e6
--
-- Allow restarts with incremental loading: when already requested skip it.
--
where  fle.file_path not in (select name from virusscanresults )
```

And then after some time check the outcome of the virus scans:

```
select vst.name
,      vsr.positives
,      vsr.total
from   VirusScanResults vst
join   VirusScanReport('file', vst.resource) vsr
where  vst.resource is not null
order 
by     vsr.positives desc
```

When you replace `vsr.positives` by `vsr.*` you will get a list of all virus scanners and their results.

You can also schedule it to run every once so often or include it in the build program you are using.

[image: Sample result VirusTotal scan]